# Division with dividend less than divisor

Tags: divisibility

Let $a\geq b$.
We define the division of $a$ by $b$ to be,
$$a=bq+r,$$
where $q,r$ are integers and $0\leq r<b$.

How we divide $a$ by $b$ when $a<b$.?

Comment: I think that if you look at the edit you will understand that there is difference in the definition.

Answer (score 3):

That division you give seems to be division for integers.
If $b > a$ it turns into 
$$
a = 0 \cdot b + a
$$
Thus having the result $q=a/b = 0$ and rest $r=a \bmod b = a$.